# Meet/fullfil promise/commitment

Tags: meaning, grammar, usage

I am not too sure about usage involving the verb "*meet*":

> 1a. He ***fulfilled*** his promise.
>   1b. He ***met*** his promise.
>   2a. He ***fulfilled*** his commitment.
>   2b. He ***met*** his commitment.

The sentences using the verb "*fulfill*" are standard English found in dictionary definitions.  But the are sentences 1b and 2b, using the verb "*met*", good English?

Comment: I find 2b absolutely fine, but I'm not sure about 1b.

Answer (score 2):

This a rather broad topic coming under the general description of collocations (Def. placement). There are verb-noun, verb-adverb,verb-verb, etc. They are idiomatic and there are no real rules, only guidelines in *some cases*.
In this case, it should be "fulfill (BrE fulfil) a promise" and fulfill or meet a "commitment" (OED) http://oxforddictionary.so8848.com/search?word=commitment.

Some people will disagree on  these, but most native speakers just know them intuitively: they *sound* right.

You can also look in Google Dictionary,

as well as: http://prowritingaid.com/en/Collocation/Dictionary?word=fulfil

Comment: Your first reference, as well as [this google ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=meet+_DET_+commitment%2Cfulfill+_DET_+commitment%2Cmeet+_DET_+promise%2Cfulfill+_DET_+promise&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmeet%20_DET_%20commitment%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfulfill%20_DET_%20commitment%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmeet%20_DET_%20promise%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfulfill%20_DET_%20promise%3B%2Cc0) say that 'meet a commitment' is also fine.

Comment: You're right. Just didn't read down far enough. Thanks. I edited to reflect your comment.